# IBM Bluemix error"You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available"

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ibm-cloud, anaconda, retrieve-and-rank

I have tried to deploy my app on IBM Bluemix from the [GitHub source](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/answer-retrieval).The app is started, but I got the following error:

```
2017-04-27T23:14:35.89-0700 [STG/0]      ERR DEPRECATION: --allow-all-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
2017-04-27T23:14:35.92-0700 [STG/0]      OUT        Processing ./custom-scorer
2017-04-27T23:14:36.44-0700 [STG/0]      ERR You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
2017-04-27T23:14:36.44-0700 [STG/0]      ERR You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2017-04-27T23:14:36.91-0700 [STG/0]      ERR You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
2017-04-27T23:15:15.79-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Exit status 0
2017-04-27T23:15:15.79-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Staging complete
2017-04-27T23:15:15.79-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
2017-04-27T23:15:15.79-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading droplet...
2017-04-27T23:15:15.79-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
2017-04-27T23:15:17.52-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (54.4M)
2017-04-27T23:15:21.85-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading complete
2017-04-27T23:15:21.93-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Destroying container
2017-04-27T23:15:22.62-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Creating container
2017-04-27T23:15:28.50-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Successfully destroyed container
2017-04-27T23:15:39.36-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Starting health monitoring of container
2017-04-27T23:15:41.18-0700 [APP/0]      OUT Uploaded stats: {"ok":true}
2017-04-27T23:15:41.18-0700 [APP/0]      OUT Starting with SHOW_DEFAULT_RANKER set to FALSE on port: 8080 on host : 0.0.0.0
2017-04-27T23:15:41.21-0700 [APP/0]      ERR  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But I have installed the latest version of pip:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (32-bit)
hduser@ubuntu:~$ pip --version 
pip 9.0.1 from /home/hduser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error or warning message is not on your machine, but in the buildpack environment on Bluemix. You cannot update that environment.

The only way to get around the `pip`-related message would be to use another buildpack.
Something similar regarding [`pip` and IBM Bluemix has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961420/bluemix-how-to-upgrade-pip) on Stackoverflow.